# Django users post to twitter

Tags: python, django, twitter

I use Django-social-auth to authenticate the users of a Django project. So I guess I have all the necessary information about a Twitter user to make a post on their behalf on their Twitter account. So do I really need to install a new app? or with the info at hand how would I do that? Isn't it just a matter of posting to a Twitter API with the relevant info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you use Django Social Auth you can do:

```
import urllib
import settings
import oauth2 as oauth

try:
    twitter_user = user.social_auth.get(provider='twitter')
except:
    return
if not twitter_user.tokens:
    return
access_token = twitter_user.tokens['oauth_token']
access_token_secret = twitter_user.tokens['oauth_token_secret']

token = oauth.Token(access_token,access_token_secret)
consumer_key = settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY
consumer_secret = settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET
consumer = oauth.Consumer(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer,token)

data = {'status':'Your tweet goes here'}
request_uri = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json'
resp, content = client.request(request_uri, 'POST', urllib.urlencode(data))
```

Comment: What if I want to post on behalf of another username if I have his password ?

Answer (score 2):

You could just extract the code into your own project and that will work. But the benefits of using an open source library is that there's a good chance when Twitter or Social Network X changes it's API, the library, if popular, would get updated as opposed to you needing to make the change.

Comment: I've used django-social-auth for a few projects now. No complaints!

Comment: As I said I use DSA in this project too. How would you post to Twitter with this app?

Comment: I belive django-social-auth is just an authorisation library. Once yo have the user logged in, like what superxor, you can just use the Twitter API to send updates based on the user's credentials and your own API keys.

Comment: yes, thanks. I have found out how to do it, I will post it here soon.

Comment: What if I want to post on behalf of another username if I have his password ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe if you have the User's twitter account details that are necessary, then you can write an (django) app which will do so. You can use something like [python-twitter](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) to post to twitter.

You should be able to find more information regarding Twitter's api [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs).